# how can i make a javascript form wizard in muilt pages with a next and cancel and back and submit the last page

Tags: javascript, wizard

i am creating a javascript form wizard with muilt pages in my website
with a next and cancel and back and submit on the last page

i tried google but it shows one page form wizards

please can you help me on this

Comment: i tried the one page form wizards but i need it muilt pages for my website

Comment: u can use plugin jformslider.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you would surround each "page" of the form with a div containing the page ID or give each form element a parameter to indicate on which page it is.

Then you would create two buttons wich onclick listeners using javascript. Depending on the visible page only show prev, next, or both. Initially you make all divs or elements which not belong to the first page invisible and on a prev/next button you would change the visibility of your divs/form elements.

assuming jquery it oculd look like this:

```
<form>
   <div class="form_page" id="page1">
      <input type="text" name="field1" value="field1" />
   </div>
   <div class="form_page" id="page2">
      <input type="text" name="field2" value="field2" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </div>
</form>
<div id="actions"></div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var numPages = $('.form_page').length;
        var currentPage = 1;
        var $actions = $('#actions');
        for(i = 2; i <= numPages; i++) {

            $('#page' + i).hide();     
        }
        var $prev = $('<input type="button" value="prev">').click(function() {

            if (currentPage > 1) {

                $('#page' + currentPage).hide();
                currentPage--;
                $('#page' + currentPage).show();
            }

        }).appendTo($actions);

        var $next = $('<input type="button" value="next">').click(function() {

            if (currentPage < numPages) {

                $('#page' + currentPage).hide();
                currentPage++;
                $('#page' + currentPage).show();
            }

        }).appendTo($actions);
    });
</script>
```

also added the example to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzgFv/)

Comment: no i want 4 pages in my website with next and back and submit in a wizard in javascript or etc

Comment: can you show me a exmaple as will

Comment: can you show me a exmaple of the form wizard in your post @zolex

Comment: thank you zolex fior you exmaple

Comment: can you make that form in 2 pages (wizard)

Comment: can you make this form wizard in 2 pages

Comment: 2 pages to run php code inside in form

Comment: just include the javascript on each page and be sure your forms look like the example one..

Comment: if someone click the back will the information the person type before be there

Comment: if you mean the "prev" button, yes

Comment: can you write some code to go back to default.php and next to default2.php .etc

Comment: can you make that jquery form in javascript and i tried it can you add a cancel to form the can you hide a next and put submit here on the last page

Comment: you should really try to do at least a bit by yourself...

Comment: can you not make a exmaple like this so i can look at the code inside please thank you